# Getting UNIX commands on Python IDLE

Tags: python, windows, unix, python-idle

I was wondering if I can utilize UNIX commands on Python's IDLE program.

I would just like to run very simple commands like:

% wc foo.txt

or

% file foo.txt

If I cannot do this in IDLE, is there any other way to run these commands through Windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE is an interface for running Python code.  You can only enter Python statements in the shell.  Python statements do not begin with '%'.

I believe IPython uses '%' as an escape to run system commands.  If so, your question would make more sense if 'IDLE' were replaced by 'IPython'.  I believe the answer would still be 'No', but I don't know for sure.  Try searching for IPython docs.

Windows 10 now has 'Ubuntu on Windows' (or something like that) for running linux shell commands on Windows.  I do not know more than this.  Again, do a web search.

If you install Git for Windows Git, a bash shell, compiled with mingw64, is included.  I have used it a tiny bit.  I don't know which unix utilities are included, or translated into Windows equivalents.  I also don't know if it is available separately.